# puts() doesn't flush the buffer in io redirection program

Tags: c, linux, io, buffer, getc

the code as follows:

```c
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   const char *file = "/tmp/out"; 
   int fd = open(file, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, S_IRWXU);
   int stdout_tmp = dup(1);
   close(1);
   dup(fd);
   puts("hello world!");
   // fflush(stdout);
   close(1);
   close(fd);
   dup(stdout_tmp);
   puts("redirect completed!");
   exit(0);
}
```

I compile the code succssfully without any warning using gcc10.2.0, Againest my expectation, the two line both are output to the stdout instead "hello world" in the /tmp/out file and "redirect completed!" in stdout. When uncomment the fflush(stdout), it works!

I guess that the puts() doesn't refresh the buffer in user space, after restoring the stdout and exit, the buffer is auto refreshed.

gets() output string with trailing '\n' and the stdout buffer will be auto refreshed when encounter '\n'. Why need to call fflush(stdout) manually?

Answer (score 0):

The `stdout` file (where `puts` writes) is line-buffered (i.e. flushes the buffer on newline) only when connected to a terminal (basically when `isatty(fileno(stdout))` is true).

When connected to another non-terminal output then it's *fully* buffered, which means you either need to fill the buffer completely, or call [`fflush`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fflush) explicitly to flush the buffer.

Comment: Alternatively you can configure the new file descriptor to be _line buffered_ with `setvbuf()`. It accepts a `FILE *` parameter, that can be optained from a file descriptor using `fdopen()`.

Answer (score 0):

`man 3 setvbuf` says:

> Normally all files are block buffered.
> If a stream refers to a terminal (as stdout normally does), it is line buffered.

Since `puts()` uses `stdout` we should expect a flush
(because of the `\n`).

However, since in your example `stdout` has not been used before
the redirection, I *guess* that the buffering behaviour is not chosen
yet.
At your first write attempt to `stdout`, the underlying file descriptor
is not a terminal anymore but a regular file.
I *guess* the buffering behaviour is chosen at this moment.

If you add another call to `puts()` in your example **before** the
redirection, then the buffering behaviour is chosen for the terminal
and then does not change afterwards when the redirection is performed.
In this case, your example works as you expect (without the explicit
`fflush()`).

---

**edit**

Still in `man 3 setvbuf`:

> When the first I/O operation occurs on a file, malloc(3) is called, and a buffer is obtained.

and further:

> The setvbuf() function may only be used after opening a stream and before any other operations have been performed on it.

On linux, this is consistent with your example.

In the MSDN page for `setvbuf`:

> stream must refer to an open file that has not undergone an I/O operation since it was opened.

Comment: Definitly, it works! But I'm struggling why the buffer behaviour is not chosen yet.

Comment: @HarrisonLee As your example shows, I think that, whether a `FILE` automatically chooses its buffering behaviour at opening or at the first write attempt is an implementation detail we should not rely on. The implicit block/line buffer distinction for non/terminal streams (as stated in `man 3 setvbuf`) must be valid only if the stream keeps its original properties; here we replace a terminal file descriptor with a regular file descriptor so the buffering behaviour only depends on **when** it is chosen (which is unspecified as far as I know).